# How to is the system proxy configured in Tails OS?

Tags: networking, proxy, http-proxy, tor

**How is tails system wide proxy configured in tails?**

Tails have non-null variables `SOCKS5_SERVER`, `SOCKS_SERVER` set to 127.0.0.1:9050 but I guess this is not enough to force all connection to be proxied.

Answer (score 0):

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
MONKEYSPHERE_VALIDATION_AGENT_SOCKET=http://127.0.0.1:6136
```

The above settings have nothing to do with SOCKS.

```
SOCKS5_SERVER=127.0.0.1:9050
SOCKS_SERVER=127.0.0.1:9050
```

The above settings configure SOCKS. You do need to get a SOCKS server running on `127.0.0.1:9050`.

> Is setting those variables enough to have all non-local connections being proxied or is an additional configuration required?

No, because applications are free to ignore the SOCKS environment variables. Such environment variables are more what you'd call *guidelines* rather than actual rules. The only way to be sure is to check with tools like `lsof` (or, even better, restrict network access to some programs using selinux or apparmor rules; though both of these are majorly complicated to set up).

Comment: I have generalized the question. Do you know how Tails manages to proxy all connection (it is the case and can be checked with packet capture)? Thank you